# Javascript / API Blank Resolved Promise and Non Global Data from Request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to set then grab a session storage variable that is returned from an API I'm using. The API is returning the proper values, and these values are accessible within the function which returns the result and its status, but not outside of the request. The request:

```
var geom;

var latArray = new Array();

var longArray = new Array();

function getLatLong(placeIdent) {

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));

request = {placeId: ""+placeIdent+""};

service.getDetails(request, function(result, status) {

if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

console.log(status);

} else {

  writeLatLongData(result);

  while(geom != "") {

    lat = geom.lat();
    latArray.push(lat);

    long = geom.lng();
    latArray.push(long);

    console.log(geom);
    console.log(lat);
    console.log(long);

    timeout();

  }

}

}

)

}

function writeLatLongData(result) {

  geom = result.geometry.location;

  return geom;
}
```

I know this function is the source of the problem, but if it's any help I'm attempting to access the stored values like so:

```
   function timeoutOne() {

    setTimeout(function(){ 

    getGeometry(placeArray);

    }, 1000); 

}

timeoutOne();

function getGeometry(placeArray) {

for (var j=0; j < nightsArray.length; j++) {

    getLatLong(placeArray[j]);
}

}
```

I'm pretty sure it's an async issue, but I'm not that familiar with Async/await and everything I've tried just returns an empty value when the promise is resolved (perhaps because the data are not accessible outside of the request function, still).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What if below condition gets true,

```
status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK
```

your google places api call is getting failed (may be because you are making too much calls per 10 seconds), if this happens nothing will be returned which in turn making function getLatLong return undefined.

Check if at least once this function returning something.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’m not sure this is the problem because console.log of the google result shows an updated value. The problem seems to be with session storage.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle example of this, so that I can play with it.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable sharing my API key publicly. I'm nearly certain, now, that it's an async issue. I've updated my code in the post. Please let me know if you have any thoughts.